# change CSS style

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an element generated by the main CSS style file.
The HTML part is :

```html
<div class="footerLine"></div>
```

The style in Developer tools shows :

```css
@media (min-width: 1919px)
.footer .footerLine {
    background: url(footer.png) no-repeat 35px bottom;
    background-size: auto 86px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Changing the `height` in developer tools actually changes the height as I wish, but when changing the height in the CSS  itself, nothing happens so I assume I am doing something wrong.

What I'm trying to do is :

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1919px)
{
   .footerLine
   {
       height:  50px;
   }
}
```

I even tried to it without the `media screen` , but no success either.

Comment: It is a style that is coming from other style sheet , if you want to use your style then use more specific selector or you can use  height:  50px !important

Comment: I have tried using `!important`. it didn't work

Comment: Make a hard refresh

Answer (score 0):

there is css hierarchy, and when you use 2 classes in one selector and 1 class in other (but to the same element), then this one with 2 classes is stronger.

more info here: https://specificity.keegan.st/

You need to write:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1919px){
  .footer .footerLine {
    background: url(footer.png) no-repeat 35px bottom;
    background-size: auto 86px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}
```

And then:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1919px){
  .footer .footerLine {
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

Comment: both in the same css file?